How to recenter google map on marker move in Flutterflow?
I am having some difficulties trying to recenter google map marker when it is moved. My app consists of a carousel which sync with google map marker to track the location of real estate property. The carousel is auto-loop to show the property image with some info and its location is displays on google map. The problem I am having is that the google map does not recenter whenever the marker moves its position.
Flutterflow native function has "Center Map on Marker Tap" but not "Center Map on Marker Move" and I suspect I may need to write a custom code to enable the function but I am not a coder and hence I need some help from this community. FYI, I had posted this problem on FF community but getting no response.
I would sincerely appreciate any help or advice to resolve this pressing issue.
Many thanks,
Leon
